# Redirect host inside docker-compose network to localhost outside docker

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I have a set of containers I run using docker-compose. The network is the default network docker-compose creates, and the containers talk to each other using the hostnames docker-compose sets up automatically.  So if I define a service named "my_service" in docker-compose, I access this container as the host "my_service".

In some cases I'd like to disable a specific container and redirect all requests to it to the actual localhost, not a docker container. So instead of the host "my_service" being routed to the container with the same name, I'd like to route this to the actual localhost, where I'm running the same service e.g. in an IDE with a debugger attached or something similar.

I'm not sure how to best achieve this, whether I can modify the network itself to do this or whether I have to proxy these requests in some way. Is there a way to do this that ideally only requires some changes in the docker-compose.yml and no changes to my containers itself?

I'm using docker-compose on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04) or WSL2 on Windows 10.

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do, you may be able to use host.docker.internal to connect to the app in the host https://djangocas.dev/blog/docker-container-to-connect-localhost-of-host/

Comment: this might work https://dev.to/natterstefan/docker-tip-how-to-get-host-s-ip-address-inside-a-docker-container-5anh

pretty similar to @camba1 suggestion

Comment: Can you share your `docker-compose.yml` ?

Comment: Could run a proxy on the host (i.e. squid) and set the containers environment to proxy connections through the host or (ideally) if you could attach the container running in the IDE to the docker network, would be easiest imho.

Answer (score 2):

#### tl;dr

You would need 3 things to make it work:

1. A predefined external network for access to the host via a fixed IP
2. `hostname` entry for each participating service
3. An additional Docker service as router in order to redirect requests to the host. We will also use the `aliases` entry to allow other services to reach this router service via a predefined hostname.

#### How to

Note: Tested for Linux. Not sure, if it works for Windows.

1. Create the external network with a gateway. E.g. via the custom IP `172.30.0.1` defined beloew, each docker service should be able to access the host.

```
docker network create \
    --driver=bridge \
    --subnet=172.30.0.0/16 \
    --gateway=172.30.0.1 \
    host-net
```

2. Add custom `hostname` for each participating service in your docker-compose.yml, e.g.

```
services:
    service-1:
        hostname: service-1.in.docker

    service-2:
        hostname: service-2.in.docker
```

So, `service-2` can now access to `service-1` via the domain service-1.in.docker and it should work vice versa.

3. Create an additional service that utilizes the well-known multipurpose relay tool [socat](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/getting-started-socat) to act like a router, e.g.

```
services:
    router:
        image: alpine/socat
        command: TCP-LISTEN:5900,fork TCP:172.30.0.1:15900
```

Here based on TCP, it listens on localhost at port 5900 and redirects the incoming requests to the destination `172.30.0.1` (the gateway -> host machine) at port 15900.

#### Example

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  router:
    image: alpine/socat
    entrypoint: >
      sh -c "
        socat TCP-LISTEN:5900,fork TCP:172.30.0.1:15900 &
        socat TCP-LISTEN:5901,fork TCP:172.30.0.1:15901 &
        wait
      "
    networks:
      host-net:
      bridged:
        aliases:
          - service-1.in.docker

  service-1:
#   hostname: service-1.in.docker
    image: hashicorp/http-echo
    command: -listen=:5900 -text="hello world"
    networks:
      bridged:

  service-2:
    hostname: service-2.in.docker
    image: curlimages/curl:7.75.0 
    command: ["sh", "-c", "while true; do curl service-1.in.docker:5900 && sleep 5; done"]
    networks:
      bridged:

networks:
  host-net:
    external: true
  bridged:
```

Notes:

1. Here the `router` service includes two important things: `host-net` as network, and `aliases` entry for the network `bridged`, in which other services are also involved.
2. The `router` service works as follows:

(request) -> [localhost:5900] -> (redirect) -> [172.30.0.1:15900]

(request) -> [localhost:5901] -> (redirect) -> [172.30.0.1:15901]

3. Since we commented the line `hostname: service-1.in.docker`, the curl requests  made by `service-2` (*curl service-1.in.docker:5900*) will go to the `router` service (due to the alias *service-1.in.docker*). Subsequently, these requests are forwarded to the host machine on port 15901.
4. If we comment out the line `hostname: service-1.in.docker`, `service-1` would respond to `service2` with "hello world".

If you have the possibility to dynamically change the hostnames used by the individual services, such as env vars or properties files etc., you can make use of them, so you don't have to comment in and out every time:

```yaml
services:
  router:
    image: alpine/socat
    networks:
      bridged:
        aliases:
          - service-1.in.router

  service-2:
    hostname: service-2.in.docker
    command: ["sh", '-c', 'while true; do curl ${DEST_SERVICE_HOST_ADDR_SET_BY_ENV_VAR} && sleep 5; done']
```

`DEST_SERVICE_HOST_ADDR_SET_BY_ENV_VAR` can be provided with `service-1.in.router` or `service-1.in.docker` as per need.

Footnote:

You can run a test server on your host maschine to test this, e.g.:

```
python3 -m http.server 15901
```